# peer to peer connection without adobe cirrus

Tags: flash, apache-flex, video-streaming, chat, red5

I am developing the video chat application using RED5 and flex. I am not sure? how can we achieve the p2p connection without adobe cirrus. Adobe cirrus is in beta and Adobe written in there faq. Not to use the cirrus for production purpose.

I am confused about create p2p connection with rtmfp server. Or is there is any open source rtmfp server.

Answer (score 0):

[Cumulus](https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus)

[ArcusNode](https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/ArcusNode)

They don't have every possible feature yet, but it's pretty usable.
Bt actually you can use Cirrus too. It's proven to be stable. The only risk you're taking is that you'll need to change the server address to some other later if cirrus won't be available anymore.